# How can I save the returned value into a registry memory

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I am new to Assembly. I'd like to produce a loop counter that sums up the first 10 decimal numbers (in 32-bit). Here is what I came up with. The code must run in MASM compiler. Should not output anything to the console but save the result in to a registry memory.
Any thought how to achieve this?
Here is what I have so far

```
         .386
         .model  flat

         .code
main proc
    mov        eax, 0   ; initialize the counter
FLP:
    mov        ebx, ecx
    add        ebx, eax
    sub        ebx, edx
    mov        ecx, ebx
    inc        eax
    cmp        eax, 10
    jle        FLP
main endp
end main
```

**Solution**

```
.model flat
;.data
.code

main PROC
    xor ecx, ecx 
    xor eax, eax
loop10:
    add eax, ecx
    inc ecx
    cmp ecx, 10
    jbe loop10
main ENDP 
END main
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"a registry memory"_? Are you talking about the CPU's general purpose registers, such as `eax`, `ebx`, etc? If so, you're already using those, so it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: There's no reason to mess around with 16-bit registers in 32-bit code for this task.  `add  esi, bx` won't even assemble because the operands are different sizes.  Anyway, you probably want to leave your return value in EAX, as per the standard calling convention.

Comment: `mov ax, ax`?  Really?  `add esi, bx`?   Seriously?  I am curious, how did you come up with that?

Comment: @MikeNakis, I made some changes.
All, Peter Cordes, you're right. See updated code

Comment: As a side note, it's usually better to use `xor` to zero a register instead of a `mov`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and